# How to send email with attachment in Magento 2.4.3 (ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error )

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I am new to Magneto. and i searched and tried different solution online but they didn't work. I have an observer from which I generate CSV file whenever a customer place an order. I'm using <sales_order_place_after> to get it triggered. now i want to add the code to send the email with the generated CSV file in attachment to the customer.
i'm getting this error: **Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/lenovo/Ven/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []**

**Storeven/Orders/Observers/OrderExport.php**

```
<?php
namespace Storeven\Orders\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class Orderexport implements ObserverInterface
{
//changes

protected $_objectManager;
private $logger;
private $productFactory;
//-----//
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $inlineTranslation;

protected $_request;
protected $_order;
protected $_productRepository;
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $_customer;
protected $_storemanager;
protected $_dir;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
Filesystem $filesystem,
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager,

\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager $objectManager,

\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,

\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,

\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,

\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder 

) { 
$this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
$this->_customer = $customer;
$this->_storemanager = $storemanager;
$this->_request = $request;
$this->_order = $order;
$this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
$this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
$this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
$this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
$this->logger = $logger;
$this->dir = $dir;
}
public function getRootDirectory()
{
return $this->dir->getRoot();
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

$store = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getName();

$websiteID = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$headers = array('Company Name', 'Contact Name', 'Contact Email', 'Contact Phone','Shipping Address' ,'SKU','ProductColorID','QTY','Price','Total','CBM','Weight');

$name = strtotime('now');
$file = 'customorderexport/'.$name.'_detailed_orderexport.csv';
$this->directory->create('customorderexport');
$stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
$stream->lock();
$stream->writeCsv($headers);
$orderdetail['Company Name'] = "";
$orderdetail['Contact Name'] = $order->getCustomerName();
$orderdetail['Contact Email'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$orderdetail['Contact Phone'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
$streetadd = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
$orderdetail['Shipping Address'] = $streetadd[0];


$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {

$orderdetail['SKU'] = $item->getSKU();
$orderdetail['ProductColorID']= "";
$orderdetail['QTY'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
$orderdetail['Price'] = $item->getPrice();
$orderdetail['Total'] = $item->getRowTotalInclTax();

// $id = $item->getProdcutId();
// $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);

// $orderdetail['CBM'] = $product->getcbm();
$orderdetail['CBM'] = "";

$quantity = $item->getQtyOrdered();
$orderdetail['Weight'] = $item->getWeight() * $quantity ;
$stream->writeCsv($orderdetail);
}

$stream->unlock();
$stream->close();

//Email code
//$Email_template_name="AddEmailAttachemnt";
// $file_url = 'storeven/var/customorderexport/'.$name.'_detailed_orderexport.csv';
try {
$file_url = '/home/lenovo/storeven/var/customorderexport/1654160951_detailed_orderexport.csv';
$emailTemplateVariables['message'] = 'This is a test message.';
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_url);
$file_name = $name."_detailed_orderexport.csv";
$extension="text/csv";
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template') 

->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
->setTemplateOptions([
'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
'store' => $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getId()
]) 
->setFrom([
'email' => 'sales@mystore.com',
'name' => 'my store'
])
->addTo('saminak1@hotmail.com') // Receiver Email Address
->addAttachment($file_content, $file_name, $extension) // here Addtement are add with Email
->getTransport();


}
catch (\Exception $e) {
$this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
}
}


}
```

**Orders/Model/Mail/Template/AddEmailAttachemnt.php**

```
namespace Storeven\Orders\Model\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Laminas\Mime\Mime;
use Laminas\Mime\PartFactory;

class AddEmailAttachemnt extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

protected $templateIdentifier;
protected $templateModel;
protected $templateVars;
protected $templateOptions;
protected $transport;
protected $templateFactory;
protected $objectManager;
protected $message;
protected $_senderResolver;
protected $mailTransportFactory;
private $messageData = [];
private $emailMessageInterfaceFactory;
private $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
private $mimePartInterfaceFactory;
private $addressConverter;
protected $attachments = [];
protected $partFactory;

public function __construct(
FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
MessageInterface $message,
SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null,
EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
AddressConverter $addressConverter = null
) {
$this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
$this->objectManager = $objectManager;
$this->_senderResolver = $senderResolver;
$this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
$this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
$this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
$this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
$this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
->get(AddressConverter::class);
$this->partFactory = $objectManager->get(PartFactory::class);
parent::__construct(
$templateFactory,
$message,
$senderResolver,
$objectManager,
$mailTransportFactory,
$messageFactory,
$emailMessageInterfaceFactory,
$mimeMessageInterfaceFactory,
$mimePartInterfaceFactory,
$addressConverter
);
}
public function addCc($address, $name = '')
{
$this->addAddressByType('cc', $address, $name);

return $this;
}
public function addTo($address, $name = '')
{
$this->addAddressByType('to', $address, $name);

return $this;
}
public function addBcc($address)
{
$this->addAddressByType('bcc', $address);

return $this;
}
public function setReplyTo($email, $name = null)
{
$this->addAddressByType('replyTo', $email, $name);

return $this;
}
public function setFrom($from)
{
return $this->setFromByScope($from);
}
public function setFromByScope($from, $scopeId = null)
{
$result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $scopeId);
$this->addAddressByType('from', $result['email'], $result['name']);

return $this;
}
public function setTemplateIdentifier($templateIdentifier)
{
$this->templateIdentifier = $templateIdentifier;

return $this;
}
public function setTemplateModel($templateModel)
{
$this->templateModel = $templateModel;
return $this;
}
public function setTemplateVars($templateVars)
{
$this->templateVars = $templateVars;

return $this;
}
public function setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
{
$this->templateOptions = $templateOptions;

return $this;
}
public function getTransport()
{
try {
$this->prepareMessage();
$mailTransport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => clone $this->message]);
} finally {
$this->reset();
}

return $mailTransport;
}
protected function reset()
{
$this->messageData = [];
$this->templateIdentifier = null;
$this->templateVars = null;
$this->templateOptions = null;
return $this;
}
protected function getTemplate()
{
return $this->templateFactory->get($this->templateIdentifier, $this->templateModel)
->setVars($this->templateVars)
->setOptions($this->templateOptions);
}
protected function prepareMessage()
{
$template = $this->getTemplate();
$content = $template->processTemplate();
switch ($template->getType()) {
case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_TEXT:
$part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_TEXT;
break;

case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML:
$part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_HTML;
break;

default:
throw new LocalizedException(
new Phrase('Unknown template type')
);
}
$mimePart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
$parts = count($this->attachments) ? array_merge([$mimePart], $this->attachments) : [$mimePart];
$this->messageData['body'] = $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory->create(
['parts' => $parts]
);

$this->messageData['subject'] = html_entity_decode(
(string) $template->getSubject(),
ENT_QUOTES
);
$this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

return $this;
}
private function addAddressByType($addressType, $email, $name = null): void
{
if (is_string($email)) {
$this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
return;
}
$convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
$this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
$this->messageData[$addressType],
$convertedAddressArray
);
}
}
public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
{
$attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
$attachmentPart->setContent($content)
->setType($fileType)
->setFileName($fileName)
->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
$this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;

return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please to be sure you have a correct template for your custom email

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/email_templates.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="myemail_email_template" label="export_email_template" file="export_email_template.html" type="html" module="Acme_StackExchange" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/email/export_email_template.html**

```html
<!--@subject {{trans "StackExchange Email with Attachment"}} @-->
<!--@vars {} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Working example based on your code with some quick refactoring

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Observer/Sales/OrderPlaceAfter.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Sales;

use Laminas\Mime\Mime as MimeType;
use Laminas\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Laminas\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    private const EXPORT_DIR = 'customorderexport';

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilderFactory
     */
    protected $transportBuilderFactory;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        TransportBuilderFactory $transportBuilderFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->storeManager            = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig             = $scopeConfig;
        $this->filesystem              = $filesystem;
        $this->transportBuilderFactory = $transportBuilderFactory;
        $this->logger                  = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

        try {
            $fileContent = $this->getOrderDetailCsv($order);
            $fileType    = 'text/csv';
            $fileName    = 'detailed_orderexport.csv';
            $storeId     = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $sender      = 'sales_email/order/identity';

            $transportBuilder = $this->transportBuilderFactory->create();
            $transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
                ->setTemplateVars([])
                ->setFromByScope($this->scopeConfig->getValue($sender, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId), $storeId)
                ->addTo('saminak1@hotmail.com');
            $transport = $transportBuilder->getTransport();

            $body = $transport->getMessage()->getBody();
            if ($body instanceof MimeMessage) {
                $parts = $body->getParts();

                $attachmentPart = new MimePart();
                $attachmentPart->setContent($fileContent)
                    ->setType($fileType)
                    ->setFileName($fileName)
                    ->setDisposition(MimeType::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
                    ->setEncoding(MimeType::ENCODING_BASE64);
                $parts[] = $attachmentPart;

                $message = new MimeMessage();
                $message->setParts($parts);

                $transport->getMessage()->setBody($message);
            }

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function getOrderDetailCsv(Order $order): string
    {
        $name      = $order->getIncrementId();
        $file      = self::EXPORT_DIR . '/' . $name . '.csv';
        $directory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $directory->create(self::EXPORT_DIR);
        $stream = $directory->openFile($file, 'w+');

        $stream->lock();
        $headers = ['Company Name', 'Contact Name', 'Contact Email', 'Contact Phone', 'Shipping Address', 'SKU', 'ProductColorID', 'QTY', 'Price', 'Total', 'CBM', 'Weight'];
        $stream->writeCsv($headers);

        $csvRow = [
            'Company Name'     => '',
            'Contact Name'     => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'Contact Email'    => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'Contact Phone'    => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'Shipping Address' => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreetLine(1),
        ];

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $csvRow['SKU']            = $item->getSKU();
            $csvRow['ProductColorID'] = '';
            $csvRow['QTY']            = $item->getQtyOrdered();
            $csvRow['Price']          = $item->getPrice();
            $csvRow['Total']          = $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
            $csvRow['CBM']            = "";
            $csvRow['Weight']         = $item->getWeight() * $item->getQtyOrdered();

            $stream->writeCsv($csvRow);
        }

        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();

        return $directory->readFile($file);
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm getting this Email template 'myemail_email_template' is not defined. [] []

Comment: Please see carefully example of `email_templates.xml`. I've used `myemail_email_template` definition from your code. Don't forget to update `email_templates.xml` and specify correct module and template path and clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method where your code is failing

```
/**
 * Send mail using PHP native mail()
 *
 * @param  string $to
 * @param  string $subject
 * @param  string $message
 * @param  string $headers
 * @param  $parameters
 * @throws \Laminas\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException
 */
public function mailHandler($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters)
{
    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleMailErrors']);
    if ($parameters === null) {
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    } else {
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters);
    }
    restore_error_handler();

    if ($this->errstr !== null || ! $result) {
        $errstr = $this->errstr;
        if (empty($errstr)) {
            $errstr = 'Unknown error';
        }
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException('Unable to send mail: ' . $errstr);
    }
}
```

I'm suggesting you to dump all of the mail method parameter fields to see which one could create the problem and with that it might be easier to see what you missed in your observer (that you didn't provided).

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: @saminakhan first try to send a simple mail without any attachments, to make sure it's not coming from your server configuration.